# .pop and .union implementar de PYTHON A GOLANG

Tags: python, go

Quiero pasar esta línea de código de Python a Golang y he tratado de buscar la solución, pero aún no doy con ella.

Es un problema importante para implementar un cluster en Golang y sólo me falta pasar esa parte del código de Python a Golang, la verdad, trate de distintas formas, pero es algo complicado para mí, ya que aún soy principiante en esto del mundo de la programación, si alguno pudiera ayudarme sería de gran ayuda.

```
cluster.pop(indice1).union(cluster.pop(indice2))
```

Aquí mi code tratando de implementarlo en Golang pero no funciona:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
var cluster [] int
var actual []int
                var x []int
                var y []int
                x, cluster = pop(cluster, indice1)
                y, cluster = pop(cluster, (indice2))
                actual = append(x)
                actual = append(y)
                cluster = append(actual)
}

func pop(arreglo []int, indice int) ([]int, []int) {
    var temporal []int = arreglo
    var tam int
    var elemento []int
    tam = len(arreglo)

    if indice > tam-1 {
        return nil, arreglo
    }

    elemento = append(elemento, arreglo[indice])
    if indice == 0 {
        temporal = append(temporal[1:tam])
        //temporal = append(arreglo[1:tam])
    } else {
        //temporal = append(arreglo[:indice])
        //temporal = append(arreglo[indice+1 : tam+1])
        temporal = append(temporal[:indice-1], temporal[indice:tam]...)

    }

    return elemento, temporal
}
```